# Set of all polynomials (with nonneg coeffs, const. term 1) is convex

Tags: convex-geometry, discrete-geometry

The question is as follows:

Prove that the set of all polynomials in $x$ with nonnegative coefficients and constant
term 1 is convex.

Is this just meaning that it follows the form $\lambda x + (1- \lambda)y$, where they are replaced with polynomials? I think I'm just having a difficult time picturing what I need to do

Answer (score 0):

Let $0 <\lambda <1$. If $p(x)= \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} a_kx^{k}$ and $q(x)= \sum\limits_{k=0}^{m} b_kx^{k}$ with $n \leq m$ then   then  $\lambda p(x)+(1-\lambda ) q(x)= \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} (\lambda a_k +(1-\lambda) b_k)x^{k}+ \sum\limits_{k=n+1}^{m} (1-\lambda) b_k x^{k}$. This is a polynomial of the same type.

The second sum here is absent when $n=m$.

Answer (score 0):

The space of all polynomials $P$ is convex. The map $C_k$ that gives the $k$th coefficient of
a polynomial is linear.

Hence the subset $\{ p | C_0 p = 1, C_k p \ge 0 ,k > 0\} $ is a convex set.

Alternatively:

Suppose $p(x) = \sum_k p_k x^k$ and $r(x) = \sum_k r_k x^k$ are polynomilals with $r_k,p_k \ge 0 $ and $p_0=r_0 = 1$.

Choose $t \in [0,1]$ and note that the $x^k$ coefficient of $tp+(1-t)r$ is
$t p_k + (1-t) r_k$.

It follows that $t p_k + (1-t) r_k \ge 0$ and $t p_0 + (1-t) r_0 = 1$, hence
the set is convex.